# Program crashing when trying to read a vector of objects

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

I have the following class which has a `vector of objects`.When i use the class object to read the value of vector,the program crashes.I even tried to put in a `try block`,but the control doesnt go into `catch block`.

**This the book class :**

```
class Book
{
    public:
        char isbn[11];
        char name[50];
        char author_name[50];
        char pub_name[50];
        char edition[10];
        float cost;
        char dept[10];
        int  count;
        char id[8];

};
```

**This is the Library class,which contains a `vector of class Book`**

```
class Library
{
    public:
        char l_name[50];
        char admin_name[50];
        int phone_no;
        char location[50];
        vector<Book> v;
};
```

**This is the main function**

```
int main()
{

    Library lib; //LIBRARY OBJECT
    Book b; //BOOK OBJECT

        fstream fp("library1.bin",ios::in | ios::binary); //OPEN FILE IN READ MODE
        if(!fp) cout<<"reading failed...";
        try
        {

        fp.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&lib),sizeof(lib)); //READ LIBRARY DETAILS
        if(fp.bad() == true) cout<<"Read failure..."<<endl;
        fp.close();

        cout<<"Enter ISBN number:"; cin>>b.isbn; //READ ISDN NUMBER FROM USER



            for(int i=0;i<lib.v.size();i++) //CHECK WHETHER BOOK ALREADY EXISTS
            {
                Book b1 = lib.v[i];
                if(strcmp(b1.isbn,b.isbn) == 0)
                {
                    lib.v[i].count++;
                }
            }
      } 
      catch(exception& e) //CATCH ANY EXCEPTIONS
      {
        cout<<"Error:"<<e.what()<<endl;
      }
      catch(...) //CATCH ANY UNCAUGHT EXCEPTIONS
      {
        cout<<"Unknown error occured:";
      }
}
```

When im trying to check the ISDN number the program crashes.

Comment: Explain what you mean by "the program crashes". And did you attach a debugger yet?

Comment: Also, why are you using `std::vector` but not `std::string`?

Comment: Since this is tagged C++ please stop using C-strings and use `std::string` instead.

Comment: There's no need to have comments in ALL CAPS.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It is home work problem :).Im using Dev C++.There is something wrong with the `for loop`,after entering into loop,the console stops executing,it says `abc.exe has stopped working`

Comment: @Dukeling : Sorry about that,i normally use CAPS for comments..!!Il try not to do that again..!!

Comment: @ManojKumar: If your school is teaching you to read complex data structures from disk directly as byte streams, without any consideration for padding, alignment or endianness, or teaching you to use `char[]` instead of `std::string`, or teaching you not to use references as aliases, or teaching you not to check for errors when accepting user input... then I suggest you move schools!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory that contains the underlying data for a `vector` isn't stored in the `vector` class itself, only a pointer to it is stored there.

So when you do your `fstream::read`, you're initializing this `vector` with a pointer to some random place in memory (where the `vector` data was located when you wrote it, which is likely inaccessible or the data is long gone, unless you wrote it during the current run of the program and that `vector` is still in scope), thus any attempt to access the data will result in undefined behaviour.

I suggest you move away from trying to restore your class directly with `fstream::read`, as getting this to work might be a bit difficult (not to mention the multitude of possible issues that comes with it), and instead write / read the members one by one to / from the file.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably some missing code from your example, but I suspect the problem is that you use `[]` on your vector without using the sizing constructor, `resize`, or `push_back` to actually increase the size of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `istream::read` to read a vector, you must use a loop and read each vector item individually.

For the same reasons you should not use `ostream::write` to write a vector. Although it will work without crashing, it won't write anything useful to the file. Again you should use a loop to write each item in the vector individually. It's probably helpful to write the size of the vector first as well, so when you read it back you know how many items are in the vector.

In other words binary I/O in C++ isn't as simple as you thought it was. You have a bit more work to do.